# Get width and height of div ignoring "style" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having problem getting the original width and height of a div, without the style property that is generated with a code.

This is how I solved it

```
    var currentWidth = $("#container").width();
    var currentHeight = $("#container").height();

    $("#container").removeAttr("style");


    var containerWidth = $("#container").width();
    var containerHeight = $("#container").height();

    $("#container").css("width", currentWidth, "height", currentHeight);


    $("#container").animate({
        width: containerWidth,
        height: containerHeight
    }, "slow");
```

This is pretty bad coded and it wont animate the height. I guess there is a easier way to solve this.
Like for example, `$("#container").width(ignoring style attr);`

Edit, better explenation:

In my css file the original size of container is 500x500.
But then when you click on a link it changes to 800x800 (adding the attribute style), now when you click back I want it to change back to 500x500 but I want the code to find out the original size for easier changes.

The code that changes the `#container`:

```
    $("#container").animate({
        width: 1250,
        height: 600
    }, "slow");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure but wouldn't just keeping `width:auto` and `height:auto` works? or just `width: ""` and `height: ""`.

Comment: didn't understand what you need exactly ?

Comment: Sora: I just want it to animate back to the original width and height ignoring the attribute "style".

Comment: Are you saying you want to animate to `auto`? Because you can't do that. Or the other way around? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/rhavE/

Comment: Your code should work, I suppose there is CSS issue. Show the HTML and CSS code.

Comment: what about .addClass() and .removeClass() in jquery?

Comment: Wrote a better explanation

Comment: Can you show us the code that changes the element by adding the attribute style please?

Comment: Alright, updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated:

Keep the original width and height as `min-width` and `min-height` i.e in your case:

```
min-width: 500px;
min-height: 500px;
```

and then do this using jQuery:

```
$("#container").animate({
    width: "",
    height: ""
}, "slow");
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LJDx4/2/)

Comment: @JacobJohansson keep the original width and height as `min-width` and `min-height`.. it will work. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJDx4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var curentDivWidth = 500;
    var curentDivHeight = 500;
    var clicked = false;
    $("#ClickMe").click(function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            $("#container").animate({
                width: 1250,
                height: 600
            }, "slow");
            clicked = true; return;
        }
        $("#container").animate({
            width: curentDivWidth,
            height: curentDivHeight
        }, "slow");
        clicked = false;
    });

});
  </script>
<title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ClickMe" >click me </a>
  <div id="container" style="border:1px solid black" >
   the div 

  </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/JhzAD/